# Using HTML inside jQuery code to pull part of a url and reuse it elsewhere?

Tags: javascript, jquery, split, var

**The foundation:** I have a simple lightbox on my home page (code below). It works exactly as I want it to: when the trigger image is clicked, it grays out the rest of the page and adds HTML to create an iframe for the text-based page that I want to display.

**The problem:** *I need to create a lightbox where the content is dynamically chosen depending on the image that is clicked*. The URLs will correspond to each other -- for example, if the user clicks "/media/X.png," he/she will be presented with a lightbox containing the iframe of the page "/X.html."

How can I accomplish this? My first stab at it is below (after the original, static lightbox code). It's cobbled together from various things I've read online and other answers to similar questions on StackOverflow, but I'm super new to jQuery / basically known no Javascript and I suspect I'm misusing variable assignment and the "split" function.

Many thanks.

EDIT: Someone has helped me insert the variable into the HTML (below). However, I think I'm assigning the variables incorrectly (see the beginning of the second block of code). Here's what I'm trying to do with each variable:
1. pre_lightbox_trigger: grab the string "X.png" from the image that the user has clicked.
2. lightbox_trigger: grab "X" only (remove ".png").
3. lightbox_trigger_href: make X into "X.html", and make it a link.

Code:

Original, static lightbox:

```
$(document).ready(function($) {
$('.lightbox_trigger').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    if ($('#lightbox').length > 0) {
        $('#lightbox').show();
    }
    else {
        var lightbox =
        '<div id="lightbox">' +
            '<div id="content">' +
                '<iframe src="why.html" id="lightframe" frameborder="0" seamless>' +
                '</iframe>' +
            '</div>' +
            '<p>Click outside to close</p>' +
        '</div>';
        $('body').append(lightbox);
    }
    $(document).on('click', '#lightbox', function() {
        $('#lightbox').hide();
    });
});
});
```

My attempt to create a dynamic link:

```
$(document).ready(function($) {
$('.lightbox_trigger').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var pre_lightbox_trigger = location.'.lightbox_trigger'.split('/').pop();
    var lightbox_trigger = pre_lightbox_trigger.split('.').pop(1);
    var lightbox_trigger_href = lightbox_trigger + ".html";
    if ($('#lightbox').length > 0) {
        $('#lightbox').show();
    }
    else {
        var lightbox =
        '<div id="lightbox">' +
            '<div id="content">' +
                '<iframe src=$lightbox_trigger_href id="lightframe" frameborder="0" seamless>' +
                '</iframe>' +
            '</div>' +
            '<p>Click outside to close</p>' +
        '</div>';
        $('body').append(lightbox);
    }
    $(document).on('click', '#lightbox', function() {
        $('#lightbox').hide();
    });
});
});
```

**EDIT #2:** Currently my "static" version of the lightbox is only for "trigger_small.png." However, I want a lightbox to appear when other images are clicked as well (for example, "vio_mass.png"). See below for sample HTML:

```
        <div id="trigger">
            <a class="lightbox_trigger" href="media/trigger_small.png">
                <img src="media/trigger_small.png">
            </a>
        </div>
        <div class="cat" id="violence_cat">
            <div class="cat_grid" id="vio_1">
            </div>
            <div class="cat_grid" id="vio_2">
                <img src="media/vio_mass.png">
            </div>
...etc.
```

Comment: Post the `html` containing the pictures.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of

```
var lightbox =
    '<div id="lightbox">' +
        '<div id="content">' +
            '<iframe src=$lightbox_trigger_href id="lightframe" frameborder="0" seamless>' +
            '</iframe>' +
        '</div>' +
        '<p>Click outside to close</p>' +
    '</div>';
```

You would do

```
var lightbox =
    '<div id="lightbox">' +
        '<div id="content">' +
            '<iframe src=' + lightbox_trigger_href + ' id="lightframe" frameborder="0" seamless>' +
            '</iframe>' +
        '</div>' +
        '<p>Click outside to close</p>' +
    '</div>';
```

Comment: Thank you! I think there's still something wrong with my original variable assignment, though. I also tried "this," but it didn't work. Here's that first part again:
`$(document).ready(function($) {
 $('.lightbox_trigger').click(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  var pre_lightbox_trigger = location.(this).split('/').pop();
  var lightbox_trigger = pre_lightbox_trigger.split('.').pop(1);
  var lightbox_trigger_href = lightbox_trigger + ".html";`

Comment: @ethanjrt don't put parenthesis around `this`

Comment: I guess, what is `pre_lightbox_trigger` suppose to contain?

Comment: Parentheses removed. Here's what I'm trying to do with each variable: 1. pre_lightbox_trigger: grab the string "X.png" from the image that the user has clicked. 2. lightbox_trigger: grab "X" only (remove ".png"). 3. lightbox_trigger_href: make X into "X.html", and make it a link.

Comment: `this.src` returns the source of the picture

Comment: So now my first line is `var pre_lightbox_trigger = this.src.split('/').pop();`. So for the image media/X.png, pre_lightbox_trigger is now set to "X.png"? There must be something wrong with the next two lines, then? (Edit: Also tried $(this).src. Same null result.)

Comment: I'm following. The final variable is definitely right, but nothing's showing up on click, so there must be something wrong with the way we're inserting the variable into the HTML? I opened up a chat on your jsfiddle. Thanks for working through this with me!

Comment: It all looks good, as long as the page you're requesting is in the same root directory.

Comment: SOLVED! There were two issues that made my code fail where your jfiddle worked: 1) "preventDefault" made the following line's "this" nonsensical. I fixed this by removing the <a> link around the image and just adding a pointer cursor on mouseover to the image itself, so that I could remove "preventDefault" entirely. 2) I had to add a space after the opening single quote after I passed the href: 'id="lightframe"... --> ' id="lightframe"... Thank you so much for your patience!